# Check if a classes Property or Method is declared as sealed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, reflection

I've got following derivations:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    string myProperty {get;}
}

class abstract MyBaseClass : IMyInterface // Base class is defining myProperty as abstract
{
    public abstract string myProperty {get;}
}

class Myclass : MyBaseClass // Base class is defining myProperty as abstract
{
    public sealed override string myProperty 
    {
        get { return "value"; }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to check if a member of a class is declared as sealed. Somewhat like that:

```
PropertyInfo property = typeof(Myclass).GetProperty("myProperty")

bool isSealed = property.GetMethod.IsSealed; // IsSealed does not exist
```

Sense of all this is to be able to run a test, that checks the code/project for consistency.

Following test fails:

```
PropertyInfo property = typeof(Myclass).GetProperty("myProperty")

Assert.IsFalse(property.GetMethod.IsVirtual);
```

Comment: Properties can't be sealed.  Classes can.

Comment: `bool isSealed = !property.GetMethod.IsVirtual;`

Comment: In C# methods are "sealed" (can't be overridden) by default.  You have to explicitly mark them as `virtual` which is why it makes more sense to check for a virtual method than a "sealed" one.

Comment: The point is, that the method is actually marked as virtual. Look at my edit.

Comment: @MarkusWeber Ah I see that now.  I've added an answer since that duplicate doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: I'm not really understanding those downvotes. Is something wrong with that question?

Comment: I can't speak for everyone, but until the sample code and expected results were added it was a bit vague.    Unfortunately downvotes don't get retracted very often even after questions are improved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to assert that a method cannot be overridden.  In that case You want a combination of the the [`IsFinal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isfinal(v=vs.110).aspx) and `IsVirtual` properties:

```
PropertyInfo property = typeof(Myclass).GetProperty("myProperty")

Assert.IsTrue(property.GetMethod.IsFinal || !property.GetMethod.IsVirtual);
```

Some notes from MSDN:

> To determine if a method is overridable, it is not sufficient to check that `IsVirtual` is true. For a method to be overridable, `IsVirtual` must be true and `IsFinal` must be false. For example, a method might be non-virtual, but it implements an interface method. The common language runtime requires that all methods that implement interface members must be marked as virtual; therefore, the compiler marks the method virtual final. So there are cases where a method is marked as virtual but is still not overridable.